Can I change the ASP.net POST limit size for my Jellyfin Plugin?
I am currently working on a Jellyfin plugin, which involves file uploads from the client to the server. This works fine for files smaller than 30MB. Files above 30MB won't get sent because of a POST request limit set. Is there a way to change this limit, either inside the Plugin Configuration itself or inside the Jellyfin Server?
I have tried to add a Middleware inside Plugin.cs. I get the error "The name 'PluginEntryPoint' does not exist in the current context"
    private void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        var appBuilder = PluginEntryPoint.ApplicationBuilder;

        // Configure middleware to increase the max request body size
        appBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Set the maximum request body size to 50MB
            context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;

            await next();
        });
    }

